# How to get value from nested component in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have an item component & a quantity component with buttons that increase and decrease the quantity.  What I need to do is, increase an private value inside `<quantity-component>` and when I invoke `addToCart()` from `<item-component>` I need to be able to get the quantity value inside `<quantity-component>`

Is this possible?  I'd like to **avoid** using a service if possible, simply because it will only be used to track the 1 value.

```
//item.component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { QuantityComponent } from './subcomponents/quantity.component/quantity.component'


@Component({
  selector: 'item-component',
  entryComponents: [ QuantityComponent ],
  templateUrl: 'store.item.component.pug',
  providers: [ QuantityComponent],

})
export class ItemComponent {
  items:StoreItem[] = [];
  @ViewChild(QuantityComponent)

  constructor(private storeItemList: StoreItemsList, private quantityComponent: QuantityComponent) {
    console.info("item component")
  }

  addToCart(index){
      //THIS ONLY RETURNS 1 EVEN AFTER INCREASING THE QUANTITY VIA increase()
    console.log(this.quantityComponent.getQuantity());
    console.log('add to cart');
  }


}

//quantity.component.ts

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'quantity-component',

    styleUrls:['quantity.component.css'],
    templateUrl: 'quantity.component.pug'
})
export class QuantityComponent{
    @Input() item: string;

    public quantity:number = 1;
    constructor() {}

    increase(){
        this.quantity++;
    }
    decrease(){
        if(this.quantity>0){
            this.quantity--;
        }else{
            this.quantity = 0;
        }
    }
    getQuantity(){
        console.log(this.quantity);
        return this.quantity;
    }

}
```

Comment: Go with an EvenEmitter, check out: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent

Comment: I'm not listening for a child event though.  I need to get a value from a child when a Parent event takes place.

Answer (score 0):

I´m wondering how your app compiles at all. Components and other directives are not injected via constructor parameters, but declared in your module. The @ViewChild ist just a decorator and the member is acting like any other. I fixed your ItemComponent:

```
export class ItemComponent {

    @ViewChild(QuantityComponent) quantityComponent; // gets bound to QantityComponent by decorator

    constructor() {
        console.info("item component")
    }

    addToCart(index){
        this.quantityComponent.increase();
        console.log(this.quantityComponent.getQuantity()); // 2, 3, 4
        console.log('add to cart');
    }

}
```